# How to highlight a cell when I double click on another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Friends I am using MS Excel 2010 and I want when I double click on a cell say a1 it should highlight c1 cell. Similarly when I double click on a2 cell it should highlight c2 cell. It is possible by using any formula or VBA coding. Please help…

Comment: thanks Gary's Student your codes are working great....one more help i require-

Comment: As I am using MS Excel 2010 and I want As I type any value or word in a1 cell, it should automatically be transferred into d1 cell and a1 cell should get blank again. Similarly if i enter any value in a2 cell then it should automatically be transferred in d2 cell and so on... Please suggest me any way, formula or VBA coding to do that…thanks…

Answer (score 1):

First install the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Cells(Target.Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
End Sub
```

If you double-click on any cell in column **A**, the cell in column **C** will be hi-lighted.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Is there an advantage to dimensioning the range object instead of just using `RANGE("A:A")` directly in the `INTERSECT` function?

Comment: @EngineerToast  The only advantage is to me.  It is much easier for me to mentally encapsulate code if the expressions are simple.